# List.find error in ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListsController#show

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and i have an issue. I am trying to delete a listing, however, i  get an error. It worked before but i dont know what happen. I am hoping someone can help. The states that it can not find the List "id".

```
Here is the error: 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListsController#show
Extracted source (around line #66)
              
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_list
      **@list = List.find(params[:id])**
    end
```

Context has changed to:
app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:66:in `set_list'

```
Here is the code:

show.html.eb:

    <div>
        <% if current_user == @list.user %> 
           <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="text-dark fs-4" style="text-decoration:none" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">

...
              </a> 
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><%= button_to 'Delete post', @list, method: :delete, class:"dropdown-item" %></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       <% end %>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 

 
list.rb:

    class List < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :category
        belongs_to :user
      
        has_one_attached :file, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

Here is a part of the List controller:

```
private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_list
      @list = List.find(params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
    end
```

server logs:

```
Started DELETE "/lists/27" for ::1 at 2024-01-27 18:00:56 -0500
Processing by ListsController#destroy as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "id"=>"27"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  List Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `lists`.* FROM `lists` WHERE `lists`.`id` = 27 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:67:in `set_list'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:56:in `destroy'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `active_storage_attachments`.* FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`record_id` = 27 AND `active_storage_attachments`.`record_type` = 'List' AND `active_storage_attachments`.`name` = 'file' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:56:in `destroy'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`id` = 69
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:56:in `destroy'
  List Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM `lists` WHERE `lists`.`id` = 27
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:56:in `destroy'
  TRANSACTION (1.7ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:56:in `destroy'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/lists
Completed 302 Found in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms | Allocations: 4784)


Started GET "/lists" for ::1 at 2024-01-27 18:00:56 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lists"):

Started GET "/lists/27" for ::1 at 2024-01-27 18:00:57 -0500
Processing by ListsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"27"}
  List Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `lists`.* FROM `lists` WHERE `lists`.`id` = 27 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:67:in `set_list'
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 871)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find List with 'id'=27):

app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:67:in `set_list'
```

Comment: Can you add the server logs that you see when trying to perform the delete? This seems like the default code when generating a scaffold.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i posted the server logs for you

Comment: if that is what you wanted

Comment: I think i may have found it , so, I deleted record / id 27, right?  but then the server does a GET for record 27, which is not found b/c i deleted it . I think that is happening here.

Comment: i found it, i was right the error was here def destroy
    @list.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Listing was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

Comment: i changed redirect_to lists_url to (redirect_to root_path)

Comment: @SebastiánPalma thanks for pointing me in the ritgh direction

Comment: That's cool. You can answer and accept your own question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're querying the DB for an object that isn't there using a method that will raise an exception when the object isn't found.

First, use something like this instead:

```rb
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_list
      @list = List.find_by(id: params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
    end
```

You're probably starting out viewing your list at restful route `/lists/:id`, and Rails knows to pull `params[:id]` from the `:id` part of the route (the colon identifies it as a route param).

You're then triggering a request to your destroy endpoint, which is successful, and `ListsController#destroy` action then tries to redirect you to `ListsController#index` (GET /lists); however, your logs read like the route and/or controller action aren't defined (so you need to fix that).

Next, your logs indicate you're trying to go back to `ListsController#show` for the same record ID you'd already deleted, at which point your `set_list` `before_action` is trying to fetch the deleted record and raising an exception.

Switching from `find` to `find_by` will suppress the exception and simply set `@list = nil`. You will then need to add handling for when `@list` is nil, like calling `@list&.destroy` in your destroy action or having your show action define an error flash and redirect to `lists_path` `if @list.blank?`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions